# What is wrong in my modification of a paper?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I am interested in solving the following optimization problem:

$$ \min_X \|XD-b\|_2^2 + \|X\|_* $$
Where $D \in\mathbb R^{n\times1}$, $ X \in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $b \in\mathbb R^{n \times 1}$. That last term is the nuclear norm of $X$. I'm reading through [An Accelerated Proximal Gradient Algorithm for Nuclear Norm Regularized Least Squares Problems](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2009/03/2268.pdf). They developed a method that generalizes the problem above. Nonetheless, I could not understand some steps in their initial algorithm. I am going to explain their equations constructions in my words so you could capture any misunderstanding in my thoughts chain.

Assume that the first term in my equation is $f(X)$ and the last term is $P(X)$, they linearly approximate $f$ around $Y$ and then they added the term $\|X - Y\|_2^F$ as a Moreau-Yosida regularization (is it correct so far?) as follows:

[image]

Now, to get the optimum $X$, I would try to iterate and solve $\text{argmin}_{X} Q_\tau(X,Y^{t})$ and set it as $X^{t+1}$ and then assign $Y^{t+1} = X^{t}$ until it converges (i.e., no changes on $X^t$). However, their algorithm is constructed as follows:

[image]

[image]

My questions is why is in step 3 the $X_{k+1}$ constructed in this way (i.e., not $X_{k+1} = S_\tau(G)$)?

Comment: Probably, wanted to have the flexibility to improve the convergence rate. In the paper, they only specify the value of $\alpha$ in Theorem 2.1 and 2.2. In both cases $\alpha = 1$ so $X_{k+1} = S_\tau(G)$.

Comment: @AsAnExerciseProve I agree. This is an accelerated algorithm in the framework of [Nestrov's Accelerated Gradient](https://medium.com/konvergen/momentum-method-and-nesterov-accelerated-gradient-487ba776c987). The step on $Y^k$ indicate it immediately, and therefore the choice of $\alpha^k$ has to be accurate, and in fact, that it the trickiest part